# Append line-break after text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a line break to a line of text I'm loading from an xml page using the following code:

```
$("#questionNumber").text(questionInARow).append('<br>');
```

The text is loading okay, but the append is being ignored.
I've also tried this:

```
$("#questionNumber").text(questionInARow).html("<br>");
```

and this is ignored likewise.
Is my syntax wrong, or my method just bad?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you see in the source using firebug ? Is <br> still not there ? Your first statement is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Markup**

```
<div id='temp'></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#temp').text("hello").html($("#temp").html() + "<br/> how do you do? "); //This is one way
$('#temp').html("hello").append("<br/> how do you do?"); //Yet another way using the 'append' method.
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhVWa/1/)**

Comment: Thanks Ashwin. I'm using Jonathan's solution (x 2), but will bear this one in mind too.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than you think:

```
$("#questionNumber").html( questionInARow + "<br/>" );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jyqH/

Comment: Jonathan - I also tried this solution previously, but it has no effect with one <br>. But on your prompting, I tried it again with two <br> s, and it works. Why would it take two <br>s to give the first line feed? (I think this may be a simple HTML quirk which I've forgotten about.)
Thank you for this, by the way. It's what I needed.

I meant I used two <br/>s, like this:


       ( questionInARow + "<br/>"  + "<br/>");

Comment: @user1404304 It doesn't take two; it takes only one. My fiddle didn't show the `<br>` in the alert?

Comment: No. But this is working:

    $("#questionNumber").html( questionInARow + "<br/>"  + "<br/>");

And this doesn't:


    $("#questionNumber").html( questionInARow + "<br/>")

Comment: @user1404304 What browser/version are you using? Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Jquery 1.7.2 Tested as working in Firefox 12 and IE 9.
Just to clarify, the line feed before the next line of text only works when I use 2 x <br/>s (as mentioned above)

Comment: @user1404304 I just tested in IE7 through IE10, and my fiddle worked in all of them, with one `<br/>`.

Comment: I checked your fiddle and I may have not given you the full picture. I actually wanted a double line feed. As I'm importing from an XML sheet, which has different lines of text, the first line is already inserted after the line of text in question. I wanted to add an extra line feed (for style reasons) and adding just one <br/> afterwards seemed to have no effect, probably because it already "sees" a line break. Adding 2 works. 
What do you think?

Comment: @user1404304 If you wanted two returns, you should have stated that in the question ;) As it's written, the question appears to suggest you were trying to add one. In the end, the solution above should work. Just add two `<br/>` tags instead of the one. Please consider accepting any of the answers here that solved this problem for you.

Comment: Yes, it does work now. Thanks. It was a simple problem which I thought was due to syntax errors. I accept your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
<br/>
```

is a tag. But you used .html() and .append() methods of jQuery, both of them are inserting contents into content node.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
success: function (data) {                      
                    $("#textArea").html(data["Name"] + "\n" + data["Address"] + "\n" + data["Phone"]);
                },
```

You can use like this

```
$("#textArea").html("Line 1 Text \n Line 2 Text \n Line 3 Text");
```